# How do you create more than one schema in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a user in oracle sql database, i want to know know how i add more than one schema to it.
Because i have 5 processes, each one with their tables, i want to create a schema for each one so i can execute their commands.
My oracle is just letting me have one schema, i dont know how to create more with one user.
I came for mysql to oracle, everything is confusing to me here.

Comment: You can't. In Oracle, a schema is bound to particular user. You should probably give more details about what you are trying to achieve, so someone can suggests an alternative. It is unclear why you want a schema per process (and what a "process" is to start with).

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I have 5 process of a company, my professor told me to implement triggers for each of them independently so i want to create 5 schema so i dont need to create 5 users of each process.

Comment: 5 sets of tables means 5 schemas which means 5 users in Oracle, unless you want to create 5 pluggable databases with the one user in each within a single container database, but I think that would be overkill.

Comment: In oracle, "schema" and "user" is the same thing. From what I understand, it does not make sense to create multiple schemas. Just do it in one, a trigger is on a table so it is not dependent on another table (unless of course you're referencing that other table in the trigger code)

Comment: Perhaps an example of a "process of a company" would help explain the problem. Also, not coming from a MySQL background, I don't understand the limitation you are seeing. The Oracle model is like Linux, where each user owns their own files.